# How to combine printing and deleting empty input in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My code works but I must use two buttons to make it work but I want to combine the 2 functions in 1 button but it's not working I even tried this

```
onclick="printResult('result_container'); deleteEmptyCol();"
```

---

```
<form>
   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="md-close" />
</form>
   <input type='button' value='Delete Empty Fields' onclick="deleteEmptyCol()" />
   <input type='button' id='printResult' value='Print Result' onclick="printResult('result_container')" />
```

---

Function

```
function printResult(result_container) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(result_container).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;       
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents; 
    window.print();
    window.focus();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents; 
}

function deleteEmptyCol() {
   if(document.getElementById('fec_col').value === '') {
       $("#col").fadeOut();
   }
   if(document.getElementById('fec_con').value === '') {
       $("#con").fadeOut();
   }
   if(document.getElementById('fec_blood').value === '') {
       $("#blood").fadeOut();
   }

}
```

Comment: I want to delete first the empty fields before printing it

Comment: Wel the above shoul have worked but you can try the following: `onclick = 'function () {deleteEmptyCol(); printResult("result_container");}'`

Comment: yah, I just realized that it's working and my new problem is to prioritize the delete function before printing... how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to make a new function and call the two functions inside it.

**js**

```
function print_del() {
    printResult('result_container');
    deleteEmptyCol();
}
```

**HTML**

```
onclick="print_del();"
```

---

My solution, thankz for the idea...

```
function del_print() {
   deleteEmptyCol();
   setTimeout(function(){printResult('result_container');},1000);
}
```

Comment: oh thanks for your idea but I think my analysis of my problem is wrong. I guess the print is going first then the delete, because in the preview of print, the empty did not fade out. How can make the delete prioritize? before the print funtion.

Comment: @Ghost please explain what exactly what you want ?

Comment: I want to delete the empty field before printing it

Comment: @Ghost Try calling delete function first  `function print_del({deleteEmptyCol();printResult('result_container'); }`

Comment: I already tried, I guess it's working but the print preview still shows the empty field... I guess i'll stick with 2 buttons?